# Fancybox 2 problems opening html pages

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've this simple html code:

```
<p><a class="doc" href="ajax_content.html">Test</a></p>
```

and this javascript

```
$('a.doc').fancybox({'autoDimensions':false, 'width':'60%', 'height':'70%', 'titleShow':false});
```

this works fine in fancybox 1.x but in version 2 it returns:

```
The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use iframe for that:

```
    $(".doc").fancybox({
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : '75%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
```

Comment: iframe is not the best for me. I need to load snippets of code without all html structure

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

HTML:

```
<p><a class="doc fancybox.ajax" href="/absolute/path/to/ajax_content.html">Test</a></p>
```

JS part:

```
 $('a.doc').fancybox();
```

Comment: autoDimensions is not a Fancybox v2.x option use autoSize instead; additionally you would need to test you code in a server. Fancybox won't find the ajax content running locally.